# Equilibria and stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Find all equilibria for the following system and determine their stability:

$$x'=y^2-4$$
$$y'=x^2-1$$

Comment: I have found the null-clines and equilibrium points, but i am uncertain about determining their stability.

Comment: Is $x'=\frac{dx}{dy}$ or $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: it is x'= dx/dy for this problem

Comment: yes i meant to write x′=dx/dt

Comment: @jesse: Be careful with certain types of eigenvalues (real part is zero) like centers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We find four critical points as:

$$(x, y) = (-1,-2),(1,-2), (-1,2), (1,2)$$

We evaluate the Jacobian of the system as:

$$J(x, y) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 2 y \\
 2 x & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

We now evaluate the eigenvalues at **each** critical point and find two centers and two saddles.

A phase portrait with nullclines shows:

[image]

Comment: your help is appreciated

Comment: Yes they did i just wanted to verify that i drew my phase portrait correctly

Comment: One cannot judge the stability of an equilibrium of a nonlinear system if linearization has eigenvalues with real part zero.